# Connecting to Aerospike DB(from google cloud) using Golang in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I installed Aerospike using oneclick installer from google cloud.

I am trying to connect to aerospike from Golang(gin gonic) using aerospike-client-go like this:

```
    client, err := NewClient("ip", 3000) #I tried all three types of
    #urls localhost, internal ip, external ip but nothing worked.
```

I read in another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27465052/google-app-engine-fails-to-connect-aerospike-installed-on-google-compute-engine) that we should connect to GCE rather than aerospike. I didnt understand. If that is the answer, can you please tell me how ?

Comment: I understand from that other question that the Java aerospike client tries to create a new thread and that is not allowed on appengine. I don't know if that is the case with the go client too, but have you tried connecting from a local go deployment to see if this is an app engine limitation? If that is the case, you can try using a go managed vm. Managed vms are similar to app engine but without its limitations.

Comment: I tried with aerospike on digital ocean and it worked on local deployment.

Comment: In GAE you can't do normal http action  you need to use. Urlfetch.

Comment: @MIkCode Are you saying that NewClient provided by aerospike-client-go doesnt work for GAE without modifications ? Because I dont know what aerospike-client-go( a library) is using behind NewClient. I will check it.

Comment: You can't connect from GAE to an GCE Aerospike Server. What the answer on the other question says it that you create a small instace at GCE that takes HTTP requests from your GAE app, connects to AS (GCE to GCE) and then serve the response.

Comment: We used Aerospike towards the end of my CSU Fresno adv. web programming class: Check out the last couple of videos in [this playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLSak_q1UXfPp2VwUQ4ZdUVJdMO6pfi5v_). Then check out the [code samples at this repo](https://github.com/GoesToEleven/GolangTraining/).